Botones Mercadopago No funcionan en movil si en PC
tengo un problemilla que no se como resolverlo pues no encuentro la falla, lo curioso es que hasta hace un par de meses funcionaba bien , los botones de pago solo son operativos en dispositivo moviles/ celulares pero en PC no funcionan. Antes funcionaba todo perfecto , alguien tiene idea ?
dejo el URL donde intento reparar

https://www.kidsshield.com.ar/payment.html


<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){function $MPC_load(){window.$MPC_loaded !== true && (function(){var s = document.createElement("script");s.type = "text/javascript";s.async = true;s.src = document.location.protocol+"//secure.mlstatic.com/mptools/render.js";var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);window.$MPC_loaded = true;})();}window.$MPC_loaded !== true ? (window.attachEvent ?window.attachEvent('onload', $MPC_load) : window.addEventListener('load', $MPC_load, false)) : null;})();</script>

            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 text-center">
                        <a mp-mode="dftl" href="https://mpago.la/2G3Tjew" name="MP-payButton" class="blue-ar-l-rn-none" style="width:275px;">Pagar Licencia 15 Dias</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 text-center">
                        <a mp-mode="dftl" href="https://mpago.la/1w1Ef6W" name="MP-payButton" class="blue-ar-l-rn-none" style="width:275px;">Pagar Licencia 90 Dias</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 text-center">
                        <a mp-mode="dftl" href="https://mpago.la/23zcj1W" name="MP-payButton" class="blue-ar-l-rn-none" style="width:275px;">Pagar Licencia 182 Dias</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 text-center">
                        <a mp-mode="dftl" href="https://mpago.la/2GiNunD" name="MP-payButton" class="blue-ar-l-rn-none" style="width:275px;">Pagar Licencia 365 Dias</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 text-center">
                        <a mp-mode="dftl" href="https://mpago.la/1cs5Sd3" name="MP-payButton" class="blue-ar-l-rn-none" style="width:275px;">Regalo</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 text-center">
                        <a mp-mode="dftl" href="https://mpago.la/26ydJ6j" name="MP-payButton" class="blue-ar-l-rn-none" style="width:275px;">Pagar Instalacion Remota</a>
                       
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>



